# Regex to extract text between two character patterns

Tags: regex, parsing

I have multiple rows of data that look like the following:

**dgov-nonprod-adp-personal.groups**

**dgov-prod-gcp-sensitive.groups**

I want to get the text between the last hyphen and before the period so:

**personal**

**sensitive**

I have this regex `(?:prod-(.*)-)(.*).groups` however it gives two groups and in bigquery I can only extract if there is one group, what would the regex be to just extract the text i want?

Note: after the second hyphen and before the third it will always be prod or nonprod, that's why in my original regex i use `prod-` since that will be a constant

Comment: A generic pattern for after last `-` any characters that are not `.` can be [`^.*-([^.]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/VrD8fE/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the BigQuery function you are using supports a capture group, I would phrase your requirement as:

```
([^-]+)\.groups$
```

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

For the example data, you can make the pattern a bit more specific matching `-nonprod` or `-prod` with a single capture group:

```
-(?:non)?prod-[^-]+-([^-]+)\.groups$
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zPU6Gk/1).

---

If there can be more occurrences of the hyphen:

```
-(?:non)?prod(?:-[^-]+)*-([^-]+)\.groups$
```

The pattern matches

- `-(?:non)?prod` Match either `-nonprod` or `-prod`
- `(?:-[^-]+)*` Optionally match `-` followed by 1+ chars other than `-`
- `-` Match literally
- `([^-]+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ chars other than `-`
- `\.groups` Match `.groups`
- `$` End of string

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/h8Al3J/1).